# C++ - Fastest way to reinterpret this data

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, wrapper, directx-11

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class DX11ConstantBuffer
{
    public:
        ID3D11Buffer *pData;
};
```

I receive an array of this class in a function:

```
DX11ConstantBuffer **pp
```

My wrapper (`DX11ConstantBuffer`) contains a pointer to `ID3D11Buffer`. The following function:

```
pDevcon->VSSetConstantBuffers
```

requires a pointer to an array of `ID3D11Buffer`s,

```
ID3D11Buffer *const *ppConstantBuffers
```

As the function receives a pointer to an array of my own wrapper, what would be the fastest way to create an array of `ID3D11Buffer`s from it? To make it clearer:

```
void ...(DX11ConstantBuffer **pp, ....)
{
    ID3D11Buffer** _pp = GetAllID3D11BufferElementsFrom(pp);
    pDevcon->VSSetConstantBuffers(..., _pp, ...);
}
```

The function is meant to be called several times each frame.

Comment: "And I recieve an array of this class in an function: `DX11ConstantBuffer **pp`" - an array would normally be `DX11ConstantBuffer *p` or `DX11ConstantBuffer a[]` (unless you're passing the address of the pointer so the called funciton can modify it), or there's an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way is proactively, i.e. to have maintained a contiguous array of `ID3D11Buff*` before needing to call `VSSetConstantBuffers`, for which you'd want a `std::vector<ID3D11Buff*>`.  You could update the `vector` whenever `DX11ConstantBuffer::pData` is set, or `DX11ConstantBuffer`'s destructor runs, and if you want better assurances around that you can make `pData` private and have accessor functions which can reliably intercept changes.

If you don't do it proactively, then with your current objects you've no choice but to iterate over the `DX11ConstantBuffer`s and copy out the `ID3D11Buf*`s to an array/vector one-by-one....

Comment: This is what I did and even though it requires the user to premake the array to send, it's working fine, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the wrapper inherites from the type it includes.

Comment: I thought of it, but that requires that the class ID3D11Buffer is known, which is cannot be, as the user which uses this class should have no definition of what ID3D11Buffer actually is, for now ID3D11Buffer is just a class prototype. ( Or struct, can't remember )